# ST_Intersects() not working properly in Where clause

Tags: mysql, database, geolocation, geometry, intersect

MySQL ver 5.7

I have two Polygon geometries g1 and g2:

```
SET @g1 = ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON ((-116.905361513607 33.73293352193649, -116.9113628095131 33.73277669453306, -116.9208047116671 33.73195459382199, -116.927685292699 33.73062425072543, -116.9463053973749 33.72802563743627, -116.9626354759477 33.72586824526348, -116.972084108725 33.72504206932912, -116.9870027158737 33.72215221500214, -117.0019242824137 33.71926025305943, -117.0145526317979 33.71681154263307, -117.0294799179214 33.71391563748596, -117.0367076958363 33.70950131718779, -117.0393418299309 33.70597834419039, -117.0431244579075 33.70223218289046, -117.0492042101544 33.69803949959092, -117.0509603806888 33.69569043681762, -117.0553507878002 33.68981753890825, -117.0577146008867 33.68534223965828, -117.0589298532709 33.68109017682149, -117.0621718797779 33.67543988287238, -117.0642654492901 33.67001280310896, -117.0649402382811 33.66385783512424, -117.0650074988621 33.65982902373219, -117.0646020361002 33.649868888629, -117.0638595655431 33.64298632688885, -117.0633877089637 33.63705507288445, -117.0640642791746 33.63090007301548, -117.0638629526051 33.62592006307725, -117.0631224288577 33.61903760069518, -117.0640696490949 33.61383368103444, -117.0638691967665 33.60885362882225, -117.0642082292823 33.60577598464116, -117.0634691445481 33.59889345198013, -117.0632694904639 33.59391332796482, -117.0642177760301 33.58870904016888, -117.0634799804067 33.58182636924709, -117.0618645110086 33.57611908123044, -117.0602496080225 33.57041180091893, -117.0578283172055 33.56185090199843, -117.056824239886 33.55401688170599, -117.0554801733519 33.54926078311808, -117.0552834893349 33.54428029155504, -117.0545498510444 33.53739722231765, -117.0518644347683 33.52788475856717, -117.0488388321793 33.52145047670857, -117.0460824802688 33.51596742109844, -117.0430587372128 33.50953306867492, -117.0409142639182 33.50192281137973, -117.0393065365662 33.4962150180591, -117.0376993447062 33.4905071305109, -117.0360926859404 33.4847991407006, -117.033875870665 33.4812184319962, -117.0297108019683 33.47500830250544, -117.023255505716 33.46924739414851, -117.0201622065276 33.46684256103002, -117.0128311837775 33.46225737261212, -117.002066345838 33.45834541662837, -116.9969519428303 33.45734051238559, -116.9958068786687 33.45756492080188, -116.9900817975096 33.45868673000007, -116.9797778583094 33.46070496940481, -116.9694754035503 33.46272191465278, -116.9648970378698 33.46361791427788, -116.9568856452849 33.46518529070001, -116.947997137755 33.46792677815127, -116.9422758377574 33.46904521292225, -116.9379653720826 33.47089077093343, -116.932431749164 33.47698729015495, -116.9308630803742 33.48431484224248, -116.9289494967652 33.49471814111455, -116.9266915158084 33.50819648986836, -116.9248574294785 33.51457126954573, -116.9226787831441 33.52402126416189, -116.9208450684796 33.53039519730267, -116.9176004304343 33.53604085240937, -116.914355836703 33.54168608639471, -116.9113779307052 33.54828166770296, -116.9107668110998 33.55040586697302, -116.9104223932621 33.55348078075288, -116.9108782504428 33.55940786321484, -116.9132796453807 33.56796446338452, -116.9132025125291 33.57198996079235, -116.9142703111631 33.57579285773488, -116.9141935107827 33.5798182762552, -116.9146509724134 33.58574508643454, -116.914574491597 33.58977041746245, -116.9147652493593 33.59474643575305, -116.9135440338263 33.59899408732088, -116.9123228159655 33.60324165968935, -116.9104911577778 33.60961282111595, -116.907857690728 33.61313171576128, -116.9020562440974 33.61826762642645, -116.8965983413608 33.62032886178638, -116.8931634116538 33.62099503479929, -116.8885837287388 33.62188307447293, -116.8785472432797 33.62483100027684, -116.871067852496 33.62828491627319, -116.8638556357057 33.63268869926113, -116.8603442241141 33.63737760029535, -116.8619452875601 33.64308117663063, -116.8643477857253 33.65163668303243, -116.8658734297924 33.66136455072436, -116.8667895352354 33.67321545122221, -116.8671721103925 33.68316522677639, -116.8695034888139 33.69574603664307, -116.8719117800724 33.70430291955341, -116.8740534332526 33.71190933539452, -116.8788300398806 33.71599941407348, -116.8824615631269 33.72031098190968, -116.8898004052813 33.72490931096673, -116.8943118308126 33.72804871165452, -116.8979460537637 33.73236057347037, -116.9036055174591 33.73527858192472, -116.9038740122949 33.73622959654575, -116.905361513607 33.73293352193649))');

SET @g2 = ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON((-117.05350995975127 33.675359910000005,-116.83677004024872 33.675359910000005,-116.83677004024872 33.85554009,-117.05350995975127 33.85554009,-117.05350995975127 33.675359910000005))');
```

**CASE 1:** When I am doing below:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(@g1,@g2);
```

**Then it gives '1' as output (these two geometries does intersect each other)**

**CASE 2**: When I am executing a query:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, @g2:= ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON((-117.05350995975127 33.675359910000005,-116.83677004024872 33.675359910000005,-116.83677004024872 33.85554009,-117.05350995975127 33.85554009,-117.05350995975127 33.675359910000005))'), ST_Intersects(@g1,@g2)
FROM 'spatial'
WHERE id=10001
```

Then it gives correct result as below:

```
latitude           longitude         @g2    ST_Intersects(@g1,@g2) 

33.62483100027684 -116.905361513607  xxxxxx   1
```

**CASE 3**: When I am trying to execute the below query:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, @g2:= ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON((-117.05350995975127 33.675359910000005,-116.83677004024872 33.675359910000005,-116.83677004024872 33.85554009,-117.05350995975127 33.85554009,-117.05350995975127 33.675359910000005))') 
FROM 'spatial'
WHERE ST_Intersects(@g1,@g2) AND id=10001
```

**Then it gives a blank output.**

**CASE 4**: When I am trying to execute the below query:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, @g2:= ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON((-117.05350995975127 33.675359910000005,-116.83677004024872 33.675359910000005,-116.83677004024872 33.85554009,-117.05350995975127 33.85554009,-117.05350995975127 33.675359910000005))')
FROM 'spatial'
WHERE ST_Intersects(@g1,@g2)=1 AND id=10001
```

**Then also it gives a blank output.**

Can someone please help as to why ST_Intersects() is not working in a where query.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: it would help when you gave us an example of the table

Comment: Also i used SELECT 1 as test  WHERE ST_Intersects(@g1,@g2) >= 1; which give 1 for your first example.

Comment: There was a [bug #68091](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68091) in MySQL, fixed in 5.7.6. Maybe it's related.

Comment: @ExploitFate MySQL version is 5.7.26

Comment: Could you replace `AND id=10001` by `AND 1=1` and tell what you get?

Comment: @ExploitFate It stills gives the blank output. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Maddys what about `EXPLAIN` ?